# conversion of function from Matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab

I have a MATLAB function :

```
Bits=30
NBits= ceil(fzero(@(x)2^(x) - x -1 - Bits, max(log2(Bits),1)))
```

I want to convert it to python, I wrote something like this so far:

```
from numpy import log, log2
from scipy.optimize import root_scalar

def func(x,Bits):
    return ((x)2^(x)-x-1-Bits, max(log2(Bits)))
```

However it says that it need to be (x)*2^
Does anybody know first, if the conversion from Matlab to python is correct? and second if * has to be added?

Upon suggestion I wrote this lambda function:

```
lambda x: (2^(x) -x -1 -Bits) , max(log2(Bits))
```

but I get this error:
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Comment: The python syntax for "to the power of" is `**` rather than `^`. So to raise something to the power of 2 you would do `x**2`.

Comment: Note that the @(x) in your MATLAB code indicates an anonymous function. In Python this can be created using `lambda`

Comment: oh right, so I just need to use the lambda so I apply it to the second argument in this case

Comment: I think there was some mistake in the original code, there should be a space

Comment: ceil(fzero(@(x) 2^(x) - x -1 - numDataBits, max(log2(numDataBits),1)))

Comment: How are you implementing the `fzero` function in python? The rest is simple but fzero is a much more complex operation. Is this the purpose of `root_scalar` (which you haven't used yet)?

Comment: yes I have not used it

Comment: lambda x: (2^(x) -x -1 -Bits) , max(log2(Bits))

Comment: I wrote this lamba function

Comment: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Comment: I get This error

Comment: Can you edit your question rather than adding more comments? Specifically, can you add how you call the function. Your code doesn't currently use a float64

Comment: I edited the question...I think the float64 is the log2 of Bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have numpy or scipy on this computer so here is my best attempt at an answer.

```
def YourFunc(Bits):
    return math.ceil(root_scalar(lambda x: (2**x)-x-1-Bits, x0 = max(log2(Bits),1)))

Bits = 30
NBits = YourFunc(30)

print(NBits)
```

I used this function for log2 rather than the one from numpy. Try it

```
def log2(x):
    return math.log(x,2)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in YourFunc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_root_scalar.py", line 230, in root_scalar
    raise ValueError('Unable to select a solver as neither bracket '
ValueError: Unable to select a solver as neither bracket nor starting point provided.

Comment: I think we are on the right path but I got this error now after importing root_scalar

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in YourFunc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_root_scalar.py", line 251, in root_scalar
    raise ValueError('x1 must not be None for %s' % method)
ValueError: x1 must not be None for secant

Comment: sorry this now after I used the edited function with only one argument, without x, yeah no need to specify x

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini I don't know how the root_scalar function works I'm afraid. I'd try either adding `x1=1` as a third argument to root_scalar or changing the solver method `method='bisect'` or one of the other methods list in the documentation.

Comment: sure, I can try

Comment: In any case, I think even if I use the defined log2 function it still says that the float is not iterable

Comment: I think I could use root() function https://waterprogramming.wordpress.com/2016/08/18/root-finding-in-matlab-r-python-and-c/

Comment: instead that root_scalar